How can I add user roles in my WP-theme menu
I'm stuck with a question. I have my own wordpress theme, but I want to add user roles to my menu items, I just don't know how to do this.
The intention is for example:
The menu says login - Register - Account
Login and register should only be visible when users are not logged in. Account only visible when users are logged in.
So I want to add in the menu option that you can indicate when it should be visible or not. I know if you have for example the plugin UM member that this will be added. But I want to set this by default in my theme. Can someone please help me?
The picture shows the menu item where I want to add an extra option

